# cual es el limite de subida en bitbucket? problema al subir 32 mb

Tags: git, orm, bitbucket, propel

Estoy usando un `ORM propel`, para manejar altas, bajas, cambios, en mi base de datos, tambien uso `netbeans` y `bitbucket` como repositorio remoto.

Hice **push** a todo mi proyecto que incluye las carpetas de `propel` y los modelos.

Se subio todo EXCEPTO la carpeta de propel que pesa 32 mb.

Hice **add, commit, push**, y no se sube a `bitbucket`.

**¿Por que?** estaba buscando informacion sobre el limite en bitbucket y no encuentro nada.

No estoy segurio si es el liminte de subida, o estoy asiendo algo mal. 
espero  me ayuden gracias

Comment: Cuanto pesa en total lo que trataste de subir?

Comment: Que contiene esa carpeta de Propel?

Comment: trate de subir 38 mb en total, contiene algunas librerias de symfony, archivos xml, algunos archivos de composer, el Runtime de propel y el generator.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el tamaño de tu repo? https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-kind-of-limits-do-you-have-on-repository-file-upload-size-273877699.html